# How to apply condition in cypress intercept

Tags: cypress

When I do `cy.intercept("URL")`, it returns me 409-conflict error ,
My target is to call a function upon 409 error .
How to achieve conditional intercept ,or how can I check in `cy.intercept(URL)` returns http status as 409, if so I want to call a function ().  want to achieve something like the below , how to do so in cypress ?

```
if(cy.intercept(url(.getHttpStatus==409){
//function call 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cypress team recommends avoiding [conditional testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Definition). For a negative test case, you should take the steps to have the URL return a 409 response. With that you will need to the following, to tell Cypress you are expecting a status code other than 2xx or 3xx:

```
cy.intercept({
   url: "URL",
   failOnStatusCode: false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The conditional statement goes inside the callback, docs are [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Intercepting-a-response)

```js
cy.intercept(URL, (req) => {
  req.continue((res) => {
    if (res.statusCode == 409) {
      // function call 
    }
  })
})
```